# js with erb produces syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had JS file that was included in the Rails 4 app. Then I added Ruby logic to the JS file and renamed it to ERB. In my `html.erb` template I have something like this:

```
<% content_for :head do  %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :top_cash_rate_widget %>
<% end -%>
```

Which results in `syntax error, unexpected ';'` However whenever I remove `.erb` extension from `.js` file it works as fine as it was.

Please note, that I also commented out all Ruby code inside of the `.js.erb` file.

I know it's not the best practice to use Ruby code inside of JS, but for speed purposes I did it :)

**UPDATE**

That's the code that was giving an error:

```
// <% if %w{production}.include?(Rails.env) -%>
//   addMozoImpressionTrackingPixel();
// <% end -%>
```

**UPDATE**

So why this line gives an error: `<% if %w{production}.include?(Rails.env) -%>`

RAILS 4.0.0

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but <% end -%> should just be <% end %>

Comment: That error makes it sound like the JS is being interpreted as CoffeeScript.

Comment: @pdoherty926: I don't think so, semicolons are valid in CoffeeScript, they just usually optional.

Comment: @RyanFrancis, nope, it's something else

Comment: What does the `.js.erb` file look like? That's the source of the problem, right? What is the full error message?

Comment: Yep - you're totally right, @muistooshort.

Comment: I'd guess you're missing a `%>` somewhere in your ERB so Ruby ends up trying to interpret some JavaScript as Ruby.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that's causing the problem? Is that the whole `.js.erb` file?